# Get Bitnami app to run in the root?

Tags: bitnami, discourse

Apologies in advance for the newbie question. I've deployed a small instance running [Discourse](http://bitnami.com/stack/discourse) within the Bitnami console. I can now reach Discourse on the following domain:

```
http://<myapp>.bitnamiapp.com/discourse
```

I've also got a CNAME pointing to this server instance. But how can I make the Discourse app run within the root? So it can be accessed directly on:

```
    http://<myapp>.bitnamiapp.com/
```

Do I need to use Putty to get a terminal window and modify the host headers? Linux is foreign territory for me so any guides to help me achieve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of BitNami Discourse are configured to run in  http://.bitnamiapp.com/

For old versions you can find the documentation here: http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Discourse#How_to_change_the_default_URL_to_root.3f

Comment: Azure 0.9 distribution for Azure still runs in a Discourse folder. But yes you are correct and I did stumble up on these instructions later. I just forgot to come back and update my question.